# Factory Girl Devise user factory is not valid - doesn't pass RSpec test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, factory-bot

I'm new to programming and have been learning Ruby on Rails for about 11 weeks.

When trying to test my user factory for validation, I get

```
  1) User has a valid factory
     Failure/Error: expect(@user.valid?).to eq(true)

       expected: true
            got: false

       (compared using ==)
```

I'm using Devise for my user model, and FactoryGirl for my factories.

Here is my user factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do 
  factory :user do
    name "John Fahey"
    sequence(:email, 100) { |n| "person#{n}@example.com" }
    password "password"
    password_confirmation "password"
    confirmed_at Time.now
  end
end
```

...and here is my spec

```
require 'rails_helper'

  describe User do 
    before do
      @user = build(:user)
    end

  it "has a valid factory" do
   expect(@user.valid?).to eq(true)
   end 
end
```

I've been working on getting this spec to pass for a while now. For a while I was getting the "email already taken" error and I've gotten past that. I even got the spec to pass once, but I was using the now deprecated "should be" syntax. When I go to the correct ":expect" syntax I get this error. Does anyone have an idea of what I'm doing wrong here?

Here is my model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  #== schema information. 
  # create_table "users", force: true do |t|
  #   t.string   "name"
  #   t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
  #   t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
  #   t.string   "reset_password_token"
  #   t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
  #   t.datetime "remember_created_at"
  #   t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
  #   t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
  #   t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
  #   t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
  #   t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
  #   t.string   "confirmation_token"
  #   t.datetime "confirmed_at"
  #   t.datetime "confirmation_sent_at"
  #   t.string   "unconfirmed_email"
  #   t.datetime "created_at"
  #   t.datetime "updated_at"
  # end

  # add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  # add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true


  has_one :list
  has_many :items, through: :list
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable
end
```

here is what I see when I create a user instance in the rails console and test for errors:

```
2.0.0-p576 :004 > @user = User.create
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
   (0.2ms)  rollback transaction
 => #<User id: nil, name: nil, email: "", encrypted_password: "", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_coun
t: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, confirmation_token: nil, confirmed_at: nil, confirmation_sen
t_at: nil, unconfirmed_email: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
2.0.0-p576 :005 > @user.save
   (1.0ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
 => false
2.0.0-p576 :006 > puts(@user.errors)
#<ActiveModel::Errors:0xa7cff88>
 => nil
2.0.0-p576 :007 >
```

When i print the error messages, I get

```
2.0.0-p576 :007 > puts(@user.errors.messages)
{:email=>["can't be blank"], :password=>["can't be blank"]}
 => nil
```

here's something interesting. Just to make sure, I did a rake db:migrate, and a rake db:test:prepare. The test passed. Then I did the exact test again, and it failed.

```
vagrant@rails-dev-box:~/code/blocitoff$ rake db:migrate
vagrant@rails-dev-box:~/code/blocitoff$ rake db:migrate
vagrant@rails-dev-box:~/code/blocitoff$ rake db:test:prepare
vagrant@rails-dev-box:~/code/blocitoff$ rspec spec/models/user_spec.rb
#<ActiveModel::Errors:0xbdf0740>
.

Finished in 0.1764 seconds (files took 8.96 seconds to load)
1 example, 0 failures
vagrant@rails-dev-box:~/code/blocitoff$ rspec spec/models/user_spec.rb
#<ActiveModel::Errors:0xa97066c>
F

Failures:

  1) User has a valid factory
     Failure/Error: expect(@user.valid?).to eq(true)

       expected: true
            got: false

       (compared using ==)
```

Comment: please post `app/models/user.rb` with validations.

Comment: Without seeing your model it is tough to say. Debug why it complains within 'has a valid factory', e.g. with: `@user.errors` before assertion.

Comment: Okay, I've updated my question to include my model and schema info.

Comment: @EricLowber try debug as say @blelump, put `@user.save;puts(@user.errors)` and look in to `log/test.log` for any occurence. Devise have own validations looks like some of it fail your test.

Comment: Ok. when I try to debug and create a user instance, the instance doesn't even have a user_id. Isn't rails supposed to automatically generate that?

Comment: I added my rails console activity to my question above, btw.

Comment: try `puts(@user.errors.messages)`, this should show what kind of error you have. Rails automatically generate `id` column only if records saved to db.

Comment: Okay, it says email can't be blank, and password can't be blank. But those are in my factory.

Comment: try create with valid attributes `@user = User.create(email: "person#1@example.com", password: '11111111')` and look on errors again.

Comment: see my latest edit to the question.

Comment: I am pretty sure what your test db already have some records, so with records conflict with new insertions. Try drop db with `bundle exec rake db:drop` and try again `bundle exec rake db:create` and `bundle exec rake db:migrate`. For easy clean db after all test assertions use [`database_cleaner`](https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner)

Comment: Respond to the errors you're getting in the console test. Provide the missing attributes and then see what it complains about. Or modify your test to output the errors.

Comment: Ok, I did that, ran the test, and it passed. But I ran the test again, and it failed. Its sending out a confirmation email. Is that the problem?

Comment: @EricLowber [read my comment about database cleaner](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27202832/factory-girl-devise-user-factory-is-not-valid-doesnt-pass-rspec-test#comment42889486_27202832). Problem in existing records in your db.

Comment: Thank you. I had bad syntax in my database cleaner file. Everything works now,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `email` attribute needs to be unique and you're not cleaning your database between tests, so you're getting on error on second and subsequent executions of your test. See https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/transactions to learn about use of transactions in RSpec.

Comment: Well, the problem was, I DID have a database cleaner. However, I had bad syntax in my database cleaner file. didn't capitalize DatabaseCleaner. Instead, has databaseCleaner.

Comment: I'm curious: Did you generate a visible error with the `databaseCleaner` reference?

Comment: No. I was just getting ready to say that I already had a database cleaner. I then checked the file to make sure everythign was in order - and found out that it wasn't. Than you for your help on this, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Just to package what Peter said, I was able to solve my problem by adding this setting to my spec_helper.rb.

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
end
```